# How to make JavaDoc link to JDK's documentation in Intellj IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, java-13

I'm generating javadoc of my Java project in Intellj IDEA, and I want it to link into the JDK's documentation.

I'm generating the documentation using `Tools > Generate JavaDoc...`.

[image: The JavaDoc generation dialog]

I've tried to add my extracted jdk java in `File > Project Structure > Platform Settings > SDKs > 13 > Documentation Paths`

[image: The documentation paths dialog]

But it always results with this error:

```
...

Constructing Javadoc information...
javadoc: error - Error fetching URL: file://C:/Users/Rami/Documents/Documentation/jdk-13.0.2_doc-all/docs/api/
Standard Doclet version 13.0.2

...
```

And the generated documentation doesn't link to my local JDK javadoc...

What do I have configured wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you want to link to your local copy of javadoc and not to the official online documentation?

Comment: When you live in a restricted country, and have to use VPN to access the documentation of a well known programming language, yes.

Having my local copies of documentation is better

Comment: Does it help to add trailing slash to documentation path? Does it work if you run "javadoc" from command line?

Comment: Just tried to add a slash and run from the command line, same error...

Comment: Looks like issue with "javadoc" command. Does it work with other JDK versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue by running a local HTTP server, and linking the Javadoc with localhost.